# Reading bytes from file without specifying encoding in Python 3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, encoding, python-2.x

In Python 2, the following will happily load the first two bytes from a binary file:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    b = f.read(2)
```

However, in Python 3, the same might result in e.g.:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 2: invalid start byte
```

Which brings me to the question: how to read N raw bytes from a file in Python 3 without specifying an encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify binary mode:

```
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
```

You should do that in Python 2, too, unless you want bugs like CRLFs becoming LFs in your binary file.